# Configure SilverStripe 3.x to use an external SMTP mail server

Tags: smtp, silverstripe

Are there some simple configuration options in SilverStripe for it to use an external SMTP server (e.g. Mandrill) for sending emails? I'm not looking at modules at this stage, I'd just like to know if it can be configured out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are number of Mailer replacement modules out there that allow you to do authenticated SMTP. Here's a list to try:

http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons?search=mailer&type=module&sort=

I wrote one of them (https://github.com/markguinn/silverstripe-email-helpers) which uses PHPMailer and is the only one I've used recently. I've found the modules that actually integrate with Mandrill are often more complex than needed if you're just sending simple emails.

Answer (score 1):

Silverstripe uses php's [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function to send the email (see [source](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/email/Mailer.php#L97)), so you might be able to configure it using [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set), depending on your server's security settings, e.g. in */mysite/_config.php*:

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.example.com" );
```

IMHO it's better to set it globally in your server's *php.ini*.

See also [mail configuration in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php)

PS: you might be interested in the [Silverstripe Mandrill module](https://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-mandrill)?